# How to approximate the integral of the product between two hat functions?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, stochastic-analysis

Consider the partition of the time interval $[0,T]$ in $n$ equispaced subintervals, and consider the family $(\phi_i)_{i=0,...,n}$ of hat functions defined on $[0,T]$ (see Appendix A below).

> Objective is to approximate $\int_0^t \mu(s,t) X_s \,ds$ so that the
>   approximation will have the form $X^Tv$, where $X$ and $v$ are two
>   vectors.

The functions $\mu(s,t)$ and $X_s$ can be approximated by (see Appendix B below) 
$$
   X_s \approx X^T\Phi(s) = \Phi^T(s)X
$$
$$
   \mu(s,t) \approx \Phi^T(s) M \Phi(t) = \Phi^T(t) M^T \Phi(s)
$$
where $\Phi(t) = [\phi_0(t),...,\phi_n(t)]^T$, $X$ is a vector of length $n+1$ and $M$ is a square matrix of size $n+1$. Hence
$$
   \int_0^t \mu(s,t) X_s \,ds \approx X^T\Bigg(\int_0^t \Phi(s)\Phi^T(s) ds\Bigg) M\Phi(t)
$$
A property of the hat functions is that $\int_0^t \Phi(s) \,ds \approx P\Phi(t)$, where $P$ is a square matrix of size $n+1$ called operational matrix of integration.

Following the technique used in this [article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2014.03.064), denote with $M_i$ and $P_i$ the $i$th rows of matrices $M$ and $P$, then
\begin{align}\tag1
    \color{blue}{\Bigg(\int_0^t \Phi(s)\Phi^T(s) ds\Bigg) M\Phi(t)}
    &{}\color{blue}{\approx \begin{pmatrix}P_0\Phi(t)M_0\Phi(t) \\ \vdots \\ P_n\Phi(t)M_n\Phi(t)\end{pmatrix}} \\[0.5em]
    &{}\color{blue}{\approx \begin{pmatrix}P_0 \text{diag}(M_0) \\ \vdots \\ P_n \text{diag}(M_n)\end{pmatrix} \Phi(t)}\\[0.5em]
    &{}\color{blue}{=  P \odot M \Phi(t)}
\end{align}
where $\odot$ is the element-wise product of matrices.

I don't understand how $(1)$ is computed, maybe we have to use the fact that $\Phi(t)\Phi^T(t) \approx \text{diag}(\Phi(t))$ ?

---

EDIT 1

It seems that $\int_0^t \Phi(s)\Phi^T(s) ds \approx P$, but if this was the case, then how to explain the use of the element-wise product instead of the regular product?

---

EDIT 2

I'm trying to use the relation $\Phi(t)\Phi^T(t)v = \text{diag}(v)\Phi(t)$, with $v$ a vector. Write $M$ as a column vector whose elements are the rows of $M$, then
$$
   \int_0^t \Phi(s)\Phi^T(s)M ds = \int_0^t \Phi(s)\Phi^T(s) \begin{pmatrix}M_0 \\ \vdots \\ M_n \end{pmatrix} ds \approx \int_0^t \text{diag}(M_0,...,M_n)\Phi(s)ds = \text{diag}(M_0,...,M_n) \int_0^t \Phi(s)ds \approx \text{diag}(M_0,...,M_n) P\Phi(t)
$$
Then
$$
   \color{blue}{\Bigg(\int_0^t \Phi(s)\Phi^T(s) ds\Bigg) M\Phi(t)} \approx \text{diag}(M_0,...,M_n) P\Phi(t)\Phi(t)
$$
but the product $\Phi(t)\Phi(t)$ is defined only if pointwise, moreover I don't think $\text{diag}(M_0,...,M_n)$ is defined.

---

### Appendix A

Consider the partition of the time interval $[0,T]$ in $n$ equispaced subintervals of length $h=T/n$. The family of $n+1$ hat functions on $[0, T]$ is defined as
$$
    \phi_0(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{h-t}{h},  &0\le t\le h \\
        0,              &\text{ otherwise}
    \end{cases}\quad
    \phi_n(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{t-(T-h)}{h},  &T-h\le t\le T \\
        0,                  &\text{ otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$
$$
    \phi_i(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{t-(i-1)h}{h}, &(i-1)h\le t\le ih \\ \frac{(i+1)h-t}{h}, &ih\le t\le (i+1)h \\
        0,                  &\text{otherwise}
    \end{cases} \quad\implies\quad
    \begin{aligned}
        &\phi_i(jh) =
        \begin{cases}
            1, &i=j \\
            0, &i\ne j
        \end{cases} \\
        &\phi_i(t)\phi_j(t) = 0, \text{if } |i-j|\ge2
    \end{aligned}
$$
with $i=\overline{1,n-1}$.

[image]

### Appendix B

A function $f$ on $[0,T]$ can be approximated as
$$
    f(t) \approx \sum_{i=0}^n f_i\phi_i(t) = F^T\Phi(t) = \Phi^T(t)F
$$
where $F=[f_0,...,f_n]^T,\ f_i = f(ih),\ i=\overline{0,n}$ and $\Phi(t) = [\phi_0(t),...,\phi_n(t)]^T$.

A function $g$ on $[0,T]\times [0,T]$ can be approximated as
$$
    g(s,t) \approx \Phi^T(s) \Lambda \Phi(t)
$$
where $\Lambda$ is a matrix given by $g_{ij} = g(ih,jh),\ i,j = \overline{0,n}$.

---

MH Heydari, MR Hooshmandasl, FM Maleek Ghaini, C. Cattani: "A computational method for solving stochastic Itô–Volterra integral equations based on stochastic operational matrix for generalized hat basis functions", *J. Comput. Phys.* **270**, 402-415. [doi:10.1016/j.jcp.2014.03.064](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2014.03.064)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the results of the article and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3576325/418542),
\begin{aligned}
A(t) = \int_0^t \Phi(\tau)\Phi(\tau)^T \text d \tau &\simeq \int_0^t \text{diag}\,\Phi(\tau)\, \text d \tau \\
&= \text{diag} \left(\int_0^t \Phi(\tau)\, \text d \tau \right) \\
&\simeq \text{diag}\big( P \Phi(t) \big) \, .
\end{aligned}
Thus, the diagonal entries of the matrix $A$ are the scalar products $P_i\Phi$, where $P_i$ is the $i$th row of $P$. The vector $M\Phi$ may be viewed as the column vector of the scalar products $M_i\Phi$, where $M_i$ is the $i$th row of $M$. Thus, the product $AM\Phi$ is the column vector of scalars $P_i\Phi\, M_i\Phi$ with $i = 0, \dots , n$. Now, let us "expand the entries" of $AM\Phi$ by the hat functions. If we set
$$
[AM\Phi]_i = P_i\Phi\, M_i\Phi \simeq \sum_{j=0}^n a_{ij} \Phi_j \, ,
$$
then evaluation at the grid nodes $t = \ell h$ gives $P_{i\ell} M_{i\ell} = a_{i\ell}$. Thus, the final approximation
$$
[AM\Phi]_i \simeq \sum_{j=0}^n P_{ij} M_{ij} \Phi_j = \sum_{j=0}^n\, [P \odot M]_{ij} \Phi_j
$$
is obtained. QED.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer too. About the "one more approximation needed...", I was trying to use the relation $\Phi\Phi^Tv = \text{diag}(v)\Phi$ where $v$ is a vector. However, in our case, we have $\Phi v \Phi$, but maybe we can move the last $\Phi$ in the middle to get $\Phi\Phi^Tv$. I don't know if it is legit, but the result seems correct since in the blue part they end up with $\text{diag}(M_i)$. About your suggestion to expand the entries of $AM\Phi$, maybe is something like $(AM\Phi)_i \simeq \sum_{k=0}^n a_{ii} m_{ik} \phi_k$?

Comment: @soundwave Answer edited.

Comment: Thank you that's as simple as brilliant! I have a small doubt, if we expand the entries separately, i.e. $P_i\Phi \simeq \sum p_{ij}\phi_j$ and $M_i\Phi \simeq \sum m_{ij}\phi_j$, and then we combine them, shouldn't $\phi_j$ have power $2$? That is $P_i\Phi M_i\Phi \simeq \sum p_{ij}\phi_j m_{ij}\phi_j = \sum p_{ij}m_{ij}\phi^2_j$?

Comment: @soundwave To avoid any mistake, you should use different indices for each scalar product. Indeed, $P_{i}\Phi = \sum_j P_{ij}\Phi_j$ and $M_{i}\Phi = \sum_k M_{ik}\Phi_k$. Now, you realise that $P_{i}\Phi M_{i}\Phi = \sum_{j,k} P_{ij}M_{ik}\Phi_j\Phi_k$ and the result is obtained by projecting on $\text{span}\,\Phi$.