# Error of approximation $\Phi\Phi^T \simeq \text{diag}(\Phi)$ with $\Phi$ vector of hat functions

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, stochastic-analysis

Consider the partition of the time interval $[0,T]$ in $n$ equispaced subintervals of length $h=T/n$. The family of $n+1$ hat functions on $[0, T]$ is defined as
$$
    \phi_0(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{h-t}{h},  &0\le t\le h \\
        0,              &\text{ otherwise}
    \end{cases}\quad
    \phi_n(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{t-(T-h)}{h},  &T-h\le t\le T \\
        0,                  &\text{ otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$
$$
    \phi_i(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{t-(i-1)h}{h}, &(i-1)h\le t\le ih \\ \frac{(i+1)h-t}{h}, &ih\le t\le (i+1)h \\
        0,                  &\text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$
with $i=\overline{1,n-1}$.

[image]

Consider the vector $\Phi(t) = [\phi_0(t),...,\phi_n(t)]^T$, in many papers (such as [this one](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2014.03.064)) I'm seeing the approximation $\Phi(t)\Phi(t)^T \simeq \text{diag}(\Phi(t))$

[image]

What does it mean "expanding the entries"?

Moreover, since $\phi_i(t)\phi_{i+1}(t) \ne 0$ and $\phi_i^2(t) \ne \phi_i(t)$, what is the error when approximating the matrix  $\Phi(t)\Phi(t)^T$ with $\text{diag}(\Phi(t))$?

---

MH Heydari, MR Hooshmandasl, FM Maleek Ghaini, C. Cattani: "A computational method for solving stochastic Itô–Volterra integral equations based on stochastic operational matrix for generalized hat basis functions", *J. Comput. Phys.* **270**, 402-415. [doi:10.1016/j.jcp.2014.03.064](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2014.03.064)

Comment: @Harry49 thanks I added tag and reference, can I add the `sci-hub.tw` link or I have to add the `sciencedirect.com` link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries of the matrix are of the form
$$[\Phi \Phi^T]_{ij} =
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&\phi_i\phi_j, & & |j-i|<2 ,\\
&0, & & \text{otherwise} .
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
Let us expand $[\Phi \Phi^T]_{ij}$ in terms of hat functions $\phi_k$. To do so, introduce the representation
$$[\Phi \Phi^T]_{ij} \simeq \Phi^T A = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \phi_k .$$
By evaluating those matrix entries at the grid nodes $t = \ell h$, we find
$$
[\Phi(\ell h) \Phi(\ell h)^T]_{ij}
= \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&1, & & i=j=\ell ,\\
&0, & & \text{otherwise} ,
\end{aligned} \right.
\qquad\qquad
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \phi_k(\ell h)
= a_\ell
$$
Equating both sides, the expression $a_\ell = \delta_{i\ell}\delta_{j\ell}$ of the coefficients is obtained, where $\delta$ is the Kronecker symbol. Finally, the proposed pointwise approximation $\Phi \Phi^T \simeq \text{diag}\,\Phi$ is exact at the grid nodes, but error is made elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, to me, it is not clear how you found that expression for $a_k$...I see that you said "by evaluating those entries at the grid node $t=\ell h$", but I'm struggling with its meaning. Could you elaborate more? Thanks. Moreover, could you explain the difference between $\simeq$ and $\approx$? Because I see that you edited the question, thanks again.

Comment: Many thanks for the further explanation. I think I almost got it. So basically $\Phi\Phi^T$ can be approximated by $\text{diag}\Phi$ only when the nodes that we consider are all and only the grid nodes?

Comment: @soundwave yes, the formula is exact at the grid nodes $t = \ell h$ by construction, but it is not exact elsewhere. Consider for instance the abscissas $t = (\ell + \frac12) h$...